# Using ConfigurationManger in F# project

Tags: f#

I am simply trying to use the ConfigurationManager within an F# project but I am getting the error:

> This value is not a function and cannot be applied

here is the code:

```
open System.Configuration
let connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ManagementDb"].ConnectionString
```

I have also referenced the System.Configuration library.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't verified this in Visual Studio, but usually there is a dot ('.') when using an F# index.
i.e.

```
let connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.["ManagementDb"].ConnectionString
```